# for each logic on multi dim array PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, for-loop

I have a multi-dim array from POST

```
[key:value key:value[array one {key1:value, key2:value}{key1:value, key2:value}][array two{key1:value, key2:value}...] key:value key:value]
```

I am producing xml entries with the nested arrays and identify them as follows:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key){
        if (is_array($key)){
               foreach ($key as $key2 => $value){
                   $array_type = substr($key2, 0,2);
                    if ($array_type == 'ec'){
                        $xml .= '<tns:PersonNamesInfoType>';

                    if ($key2 == 'ec_fname'){
                        $xml .= '<GivenName>'.$value.'</GivenName>';
                        //<MidInitial>MidInitial</MidInitial>
                        }
                        else if ($key2 == 'ec_lname'){
                            $xml .= '<FamilyName>'.$value.'</FamilyName>';
                            //</tns:PersonNamesInfoType>
                            }
                        else if ($key2 == 'ec_rel'){
                            $xml .= ' <Relationship>'.$value.' </Relationship>';
                            // <tns:PhoneInfoType>
                            //<tns:PhoneType></tns:PhoneType>
                            }
                        else if ($key2 == 'ec_ophone'){
                            $xml .= '<Number>'.$value.'</Number>';
                            }
                        else {
                            $xml .= '<IsPrimary>'.$value.'</IsPrimary>';
                            }
                            $xml .= '</tns:PersonNamesInfoType>';
                   }
                   else if($array_type == 've') {
                       $xml .= '<tns:AutoInfoType>';

                        foreach ($key as $key2 => $value){

                            if ($key2 == 'veh_year'){
                            $xml .= '<Year>'.$value.'</Year>';
                            }
                            else if ($key2 == 'veh_make'){
                            $xml .= '<Make>'.$value.'</Make>';
                            }
                            else if ($key2 == 'veh_model'){
                            $xml .= '<Model>'.$value.'</Model>';
                            }
                            else if ($key2 == 'veh_plate'){
                            $xml .= '<Plate>'.$value.'</Plate>';
                            }
                            else if ($key2 == 'veh_state'){
                            $xml .= '<tns:StateType>'.$value.'</tns:StateType>';
                            }
                            else {$xml .= '<IsPrimary>'.$value.'</IsPrimary>';}

                }
            $xml .= '</tns:AutoInfoType>';
                   }

            }
    }
}
```

This produces incorrect results

```
<tns:PersonNamesInfoType>
<GivenName>'.$value.'</GivenName>
</tns:PersonNamesInfoType>


<tns:PersonNamesInfoType>
<FamilyName>'.$value.'</FamilyName>
</tns:PersonNamesInfoType>

Instead of:

<tns:PersonNamesInfoType>
<GivenName>'.$value.'</GivenName>
<FamilyName>'.$value.'</FamilyName>
</tns:PersonNamesInfoType>
```

What is the better solution for segregating the data for each array based on the first key value coming across as

```
1[ec_fname]
1[veh_lname]
2[ec_fname]
2[veh_lname]
```

Comment: Because you're running the codes inside the foreach loop so the parent tag is being generated every time.

Comment: @maSnum, what is the better solution for separating out the data for each array?

Comment: I would recommend sorting them into well structured arrays first and then parse them.

Comment: @maSnum, they aren't well structured? how do you parse them?? that is my question.. They come from POST so I dont see how i can make them any more than they are now.

Comment: Something like http://pastie.org/3931239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you need, and it's shorter, simpler, and more easily expandable:

```
$personTags = array(
    "ec_fname" => "GivenName",
    "ec_lname" => "FamilyName",
    "ec_rel" => "Relationship",
    "ec_ophone" => "Number"
);

$vehicleTags = array(
    "veh_year" => "Year",
    "veh_make" => "Make",
    "veh_model" => "Model",
    "veh_plate" => "Plate",
    "veh_state" => "StateType"
);

$xml = "";
foreach ($_POST as $key)
{
    if (!is_array($key))
        continue;

    $personNamesInfoTypes = array();
    $autoInfoTypes = array();

    foreach ($key as $key2 => $value)
    {
        $array_type = substr($key2, 0, 2);
        if ($array_type == 'ec')
        {
            if (array_key_exists($key2, $personTags))
                $tag = $personTags[$key2];
            else
                $tag = "IsPrimary";

            $personNamesInfoTypes[] = " <{$tag}>{$value}</{$tag}>";
        }
        else if ($array_type == 've')
        {
            if (array_key_exists($key2, $vehicleTags))
                $tag = $vehicleTags[$key2];
            else
                $tag = "IsPrimary";

            $autoInfoTypes[] = "    <{$tag}>{$value}</{$tag}>";
        }
    }

    if (!empty($personNamesInfoTypes))
        $xml .= "<tns:PersonNamesInfoType>\n". implode("\n", $personNamesInfoTypes) ."\n</tns:PersonNamesInfoTypes>\n";
    if (!empty($autoInfoTypes))
        $xml .= "<tns:AutoInfoType>\n". implode("\n", $autoInfoTypes) ."\n</tns:AutoInfoTypes>\n";
}
```

---

It looks like you had your loops set up wrong (there was a foreach loop in the vehicle section, but not one in the person section) and you were creating a new parent node every time a child node was created.

With my solution, instead of adding the nodes directly to the string on each loop iteration, they will instead be appended to an array, and then at the end of that `$_POST` variable, the two arrays will be dumped into the correct parent node all at once.

If you have to add another possible tag to either the person section or the vehicle section, all you need to do is add an entry to the `$personTags` or `$vehicleTags` array.

Comment: i like this solution but i am getting every entry <IsPirmary>firstname</IsPrimary>

Comment: I just edited it a couple minutes ago. I was getting the same thing. Did you try it again? If you are still getting the same thing, could you add the output of `var_dump($_POST);` to your question? It would help with seeing how the array looks coming in.

Comment: PERFECT!! except open close for the final if statements... what did you change?

Comment: I was using `in_array` to check to see if the key existed in the `$personTags` and `$vehicleTags` arrays, when I should have been using `array_key_exists`. Glad to hear this worked for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may pay attention to your code format.

It's not so clearly that there is a foreach inside a foreach, and they are using the same "$key2" and "$value". I guess you make the "}" in wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Your second if condition for **"type equals 've'"** the *foreach* is inside of the *if condition*.

```
else if($array_type == 've') {
$xml .= '<tns:AutoInfoType>';
foreach ($key as $key2 => $value){
```

but on the initial *if condition* for **"type equals 'ec'"** the *foreach* is outside of the *if condition* thus causing you problems.

```
foreach ($key as $key2 => $value){
$array_type = substr($key2, 0,2);
if ($array_type == 'ec'){
```

**My Solution**

My proposed solution is pretty simple... simply move foreach from line 4 to line 7 and your problem should be solved (*for each* needs to be inside the *if condition*).

```
if ($array_type == 'ec'){
$xml .= '<tns:PersonNamesInfoType>';
foreach ($key as $key2 => $value){
```

I've attached the complete solution to my answer :)

```
  foreach ($_POST as $key){
    if (is_array($key)){
               $array_type = substr($key2, 0,2);
                if ($array_type == 'ec'){
                    $xml .= '<tns:PersonNamesInfoType>';
                    foreach ($key as $key2 => $value){
                    if ($key2 == 'ec_fname'){
                        $xml .= '<GivenName>'.$value.'</GivenName>';
                        //<MidInitial>MidInitial</MidInitial>
                        }
                        else if ($key2 == 'ec_lname'){
                            $xml .= '<FamilyName>'.$value.'</FamilyName>';
                            //</tns:PersonNamesInfoType>
                            }
                        else if ($key2 == 'ec_rel'){
                            $xml .= ' <Relationship>'.$value.' </Relationship>';
                            // <tns:PhoneInfoType>
                            //<tns:PhoneType></tns:PhoneType>
                            }
                        else if ($key2 == 'ec_ophone'){
                            $xml .= '<Number>'.$value.'</Number>';
                            }
                        else {
                            $xml .= '<IsPrimary>'.$value.'</IsPrimary>';
                            }
                    }
                    $xml .= '</tns:PersonNamesInfoType>';
               }
               else if($array_type == 've') {
                   $xml .= '<tns:AutoInfoType>';

                    foreach ($key as $key2 => $value){

                        if ($key2 == 'veh_year'){
                        $xml .= '<Year>'.$value.'</Year>';
                        }
                        else if ($key2 == 'veh_make'){
                        $xml .= '<Make>'.$value.'</Make>';
                        }
                        else if ($key2 == 'veh_model'){
                        $xml .= '<Model>'.$value.'</Model>';
                        }
                        else if ($key2 == 'veh_plate'){
                        $xml .= '<Plate>'.$value.'</Plate>';
                        }
                        else if ($key2 == 'veh_state'){
                        $xml .= '<tns:StateType>'.$value.'</tns:StateType>';
                        }
                        else {$xml .= '<IsPrimary>'.$value.'</IsPrimary>';}

            }
        $xml .= '</tns:AutoInfoType>';
               }
}
}
```

Comment: doesnt it need to loop through the sub arrays key2 to find the array type?